# Change JavaScript default alerts by using sweet alerts in process

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert

I want to ask,, how to call sweet alert in process.php?

example if in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sweet Alert</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="sweet()">Sweet Alert</button>
<script>
function sweet (){
swal("Good job!");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Well, how if placed in process.php?

Example there are 2 fields:

tes.php :

```
<form method="post" action="proses.php">
<label>NIK</label><br>
<input type="text" name="nik"><br>
<label>Confirm NIK</label><br>
<input type="text" name="confirmnik"><br><br>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Cek</button>
</form>
```

process.php :

```
<?php
    $nik        = $_POST['nik'];
    $confirmnik = $_POST['confirmnik'];

    if ($nik<>$confirmnik)
    {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('nik and confirm nik do not match !');window.history.back();</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('ok');window.history.back();</script>";
    }
?>
```

result :

[image]

How to change javascript default alerts by using sweet alerts in process.php file?

Comment: have you tried changing your `alert('nik and ...` to `swal('nik and ...`?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to seamlessly replace `alert` with `swal`.

Your only issue is going to be calling the `window.history.back` function. You need to put it in a callback as sweet alert does not block the thread like `alert` does.

You can use [promises](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises) for that:

So your JS code would look something like:

```
swal('nik and confirm nik do not match !').then(() => {window.history.back()});
```

And the full PHP code would look like:

```
<?php
    $nik        = $_POST['nik'];
    $confirmnik = $_POST['confirmnik'];

    if ($nik<>$confirmnik)
    {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>swal('nik and confirm nik do not match !').then(() => { window.history.back(); });</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script language='javascript'>swal('ok').then(() => { window.history.back(); });</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are very helpful, but still not working.. where do I put the library sweet alerts? in test.php or in process.php?

Comment: Put it in `test.php` in the `<head>`

Comment: I've tried it .. but nothing happened, when jumping to the file process.php, just show a blank view. Have you tried it

Comment: In your generated HTML, are the libraries there ? Also, do you get any errors in the console ?

Comment: ya.. see my code and image : https://imgur.com/a/yFwOo and https://imgur.com/a/Jl5CM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162726/discussion-between-klugjo-and-illogic).